# How do I correctly use the Angular CdkMenuModule to create a custom contextmenu on right click?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, contextmenu, angular-cdk

I am trying to implement a custom contextmenu in my Angular application, that is bound to a specific HTMLElement and opens at the current mouse position when right click is pressed. In theory this should be fairly easy by just following the examples under [this link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/examples), using the `CdkMenuModule`.

My problem is that whatever type of menu I choose, it never opens up dynamically at the position it should be. Instead it looks like it just gets attached to the html body, ending up stuck to the left of the screen below the other html components.

I tested this in a minimal project setup, by following these steps:

1. creating a default angular project folder: `ng new menutest` (Angular CLI Version 15.2.4, routing enabled, using the .scss format)
2. installing the cdk module: `ng add @angular/cdk` (installing version 15.2.5)
3. importing the module inside app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CdkMenuModule } from '@angular/cdk/menu';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AppRoutingModule,
CdkMenuModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

4. replacing the the contents of app.component.html / .scss by one or two of the examples from the angular website
5. serving the application using `ng serve`

[This is how it looks like when testing the setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnbCD.jpg)

I don't know what is causing the issue, it doesn't seem like there would be a need to add custom code or using events to set the position manually, so any help or tips are appreciated.

I can add the contents of tsconfig.json, angular.json or package.json if needed, but I did not change anything after setting up the project.

Comment: Did you import the `@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt` stylesheet? ([See also](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/has-overlay/src/has-overlay/has-overlay.component.scss#L2))